# How to write POJO for Marshalling two list of objects?

Tags: java, jaxb

```
<MyRoot>
    <Person>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
        <Age>20</Age>
    </Person>   
    <Address>
        <HouseName>Joe</HouseName>
        <Place>Delhi</Place>
    </Address>
    <Person>
        <Name>James</Name>
        <Age>21</Age>
    </Person>   
    <Address>
        <HouseName>Joe</HouseName>
        <Place>Mumbai</Place>
    </Address>
</MyRoot>
```

From above xml, you can see that person and address tag is not wrapped in a wrapper tag. I want to generate an xml using JAXB in same format. I don't know how to do that without a wrapper tag.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking into creating java object that contains a list of Persons and a list of addresses?

```
public class MyRootObject {
   private List<Person> persons;
   private List<Address> addresses;
}
```

If the above is what you intend on doing then note that the XML object will change...

Comment: This will iterate through persons and then address.
What I am expecting is person, address, then again person address...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to preserve a mixed sequence like `<Person> <Address> <Person> <Address>` (as you say in your comment to @Vankuisher's answer),
then you need to keep the `Person`s and `Address`es not in 2 separate `List`s,
but together within the *same* `List`.

For that to work `Person` and `Address` must be subclasses of a common superclass
(e.g. `class Person extends Item` and `class Address extends Item`).
Then you use an [`@XmlElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html) annotation to define the mapping between
XML element names and Java classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "MyRoot")
public class MyRoot {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "Address", type = Address.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "Person", type = Person.class)
    })
    private List<Item> items;

    // public getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

When marshalling such a `MyRoot` object you will get an XML output
with the same sequence of items as given within the `List<Item>`.